# App won't work in background android studio

Tags: service

My app won't run in background using alarm manager , job scheduler and even with work manager .
I'm trying to send device location every 15 minutes to server .
I tried all of the above ways and still my app wont work .
I took all needed permissions and even ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS with power manager for running the app in background .
And i implemented all manifest needs .
and i won't use foreground services

Now i'm using alarm manager with this code in Broadcast Receiver.

here is my code .

MainActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    startBroadcastLocation()
}

private void startBroadcastLocation() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, GetLocationServices.class);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

And in my Broadcast

```
public class GetLocationServices extends BroadcastReceiver {

private Context context;
private static final String SEND_DATA = "SEND_MY_LOCATION";
private static final String TAG = "TAG";
private boolean gps_enabled;
private String timeString, dateString;
private Intent intent;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClientLocation;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private Location mLocation;
private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
private ApiInterface apiInterface;
private LocationManager lm;
private Timer gpsTimer;
private SendApi sendApi;

@SuppressLint("UnsafeProtectedBroadcastReceiver")
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    this.context = context;

    sendApi = new SendApi(context);

    Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, GetLocationServices.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, 
    intent2, 0);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) 
    context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
        calendar.getTimeInMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 1, pendingIntent);
    }


    apiInterface = API.getAPI().create(ApiInterface.class);

    getCurrentLocation();
}

private void getCurrentLocation() {
    MyLocation.LocationResult locationResult = new 
    MyLocation.LocationResult() {
        @Override
        public void gotLocation(Location location) {
            dateString = new CurrentDateAndTime().computeDate();
            timeString = new CurrentDateAndTime().computeTime();
           
            sendApi.sendLocation(location.getLongitude() + "", 
            location.getLatitude() + "", dateString, timeString);
        }
    };

        MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation();
        myLocation.getLocation(context, locationResult);
    }
}
```

PLEASE HELP_ME!